# Bootstrapping Hyperledger-fabric environments (dev/uat/prod) preferences

Tags: architecture, devops, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

We are about to start development from scratch. Most likely this will be a single organisation network deployed in Oracle using their managed service. What is the preferred way to approach this?

1. Single network with multiple channels for dev/uat/prod
   **OR**
2. Isolated networks for each dev/uat/prod

It's understood that dev can be achieved by local docker deployment etc, but for consistency, it might be a good idea to get it going in the managed service, too.

Answer (score 1):

Among the most commonly used best practices to separate the various environments is to definitely keep Production apart from all other environments. Even if only from a security perspective. It may cause all kinds of auditing questions you may eventually have to answer as to why you did NOT separate production.

Also, if you foresee you have to go through a deployment process in an automated fashion, consider having at least one environment to dry-run this process.

Other than that, given the way HLF is set up, I think it will be a matter of taste.

Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Thank you. I had a feeling of a "personal preference" matter here because HLF channels do provide enough isolation. Having to manage two or three separate networks seems unnecessary admin overhead, but you are absolutely on spot with the audit note.